# ODataComplexValue Actions and Casting

Tags: c#, odata

So I'm new to OData and I'm using Simple.OData.Client

So my code first looked like this :

```
var context = new ODataClient("http://localhost:51861/API/");  
var test = context.For<Account>()
            .Key("00010017")
            .Action("Testing")
            .Set(new Entry() { { "MyTest",  New Test() { Item = "Hello World"}  } })
            .ExecuteAsScalarAsync<Test>()
            .Result;
```

Leads to the following error:

```
"The value for parameter 'MyTest' is of type 'ODataExample.Model.MyTest'. WriteValue can only write null, ODataComplexValue, ODataEnumValue and primitive types that are not Stream type."
```

Ok, cool, so the exception above is informative and I can work with this by doing

```
 ODataComplexValue MyTest = new ODataComplexValue();
 ODataProperty myP = new ODataProperty();

 myP.Name = "Item";
 myP.Value = "Hello World";

 myCustomer.TypeName = "ODataExample.Model.MyTest";
 myCustomer.Properties = new[] { myP };
```

So now if I pass myTest into the .Set I get a working call to my OData server

```
  .Set(new Entry() { { "MyTest",  MyTest )
```

So Obviously I can create a ODataComplexValue with something like

```
 var tt = new ODataComplexValue()
            {
                TypeName = t.GetType().FullName,
                Properties =  s.GetType().GetProperties().Select<PropertyInfo,ODataProperty>(x => new ODataProperty { Name = x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(t) })
            };
```

The above works great and I an just create an extension method from that to have

```
.Set(new Entry() { { "MyTest",  New Test() { Item = "Hello World"}  } }.ToOData())
```

However, I can't help but feel I'm missing something, if the solution is this simple, why is Simple.OData.Client not just doing this for me? Is is there already an extension method or utility I should be using to get the same above result.

Just incase its required my webapi routing is as followed :

```
   var function = builder.EntityType<Account>().Action("Testing");
            function.Namespace = "Transaction";
            function.Parameter<Test>("MyTest");
            function.ReturnsFromEntitySet<Test>("Test");
```